# Self-hosted file synchronization that does not lock files, and allow renames/moves/deletions/etc during sync

Tags: file-synchronization

**Use case:**

- Exactly the same as Dropbox for individual use, except without storing data on another's server, and without a monthly subscription payment. Open-source, freeware, or a one-off commercial licence are acceptable but not a periodic payment subscription

I've tested Syncthing, BTSync, Pydio, OwnCloud. None satisfy all of the below.

**My requirements for a Dropbox replacement are as follows:**

- Truly cross-platform, supporting Windows & Linux (that rules out Owncloud and Pydio, both of which can be shoe-horned into working on Windows but are Linux-centric)
- Self-hosted, but *not* running on PHP and *not* requiring installation of external web server or database
- Good conflict resolution (Syncthing does this well, BTSync simply overwrites updated files, there's a serious bug)
- The ability to update, rename, delete, or move files that may be part-way through a sync. i.e. "seamless" (Syncthing appears to lock the file it's synchronising and you can't move or delete it)
- A sensible sharing model which is not overcomplicated (subjective, but BTSync does not have this)
- Ability to work over the internet either by setting up firewall rules or using a relay. (Syncthing even allows for self hosted relay)

**Ideal but not essential:**

- Selective sync i.e. there's a separate interface to choose which items in a sync folder you wish to have on a given device. (BTSync claims to have this, but the implementation is confusing, it doesn't compare to Dropbox's dialog box from which you simply use a tick box for the folders you want on that computer)
- OS notifications, Windows system tray GUI interaction (e.g. ability to quickly pause to save bandwidth)

**These are not important:**

- The sync model. I don't mind if it's a client-server model or a peer-type model
- Sharing with other users is not necessary for me. I would consider it a benefit to have the possibility, but not if it meant compromising on any of the above

Comment: Your question is different from all questions at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-synchronization ?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I don't understand [the purpose of] your comment, please explain

Comment: Your question sounds like it is probably a duplicate of an existing question, so I ask you whether you have checked for duplicates or not :-)

Comment: Oh I didn't see the question mark at the end of your comment - I thought it was a statement. Admittedly the question is similar but my spec is different. Lots of people are looking for sync software, lots of companies make sync software, but nobody is asking specific questions about sync that doesn't lock files, and allows renames/moves/deletions etc during sync.

Comment: Reducing Nicolas' link to [candidates with answers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[file-synchronization]+answers%3A1) and even more to [Dropbox alternatives](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[file-synchronization]+dropbox+answers%3A1): Could you please check at least the latter and see if one of them matches – and then [edit] your question to indicate that (including why none of those is a duplicate "because …")?

Comment: I am actually looking for something similar to this a p2p cloud lets say. Did you managed to find anything that fullfills your requirements?

Comment: AeroFS came closest. You can download a version for free that works well. Selective sync is supported but didn't work quite as well as Dropbox. Personally I bought a licence for GoodSync after testing it for 30 days. This was completely different to what I originally wanted but I found it so easy and automatic, and it allows me to have remote sync nodes. I highly recommend goodsync, although it's not a true p2p solution.